# Render a view with errors and input that can be returned to AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a basic form that collects user information (name, surname, etc)

An example of one input field:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{ old('name', $user->name) }}">
    @if ($errors->has('name'))
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

I send this data via an AJAX request to the server. If errors occur during validation then I want to return a view with the errors showing.
Something like this:

```
$html = view('partials.update_form')->withErrors($validator)->withInput()->render();
return response()->json(['html' => $html, 'status' => 'error']);
```

However, this returns error 500
I have also tried making sure that the user's data is added like so:

```
$html = view('partials.update_form', compact('user'))->withErrors($validator)->withInput()->render();
return response()->json(['html' => $html, 'status' => 'error']);
```

This also proved to be fruitless
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is my AJAX request just to give you a full picture:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#update-user-form')[0]);
if ($('form').find('input[name=avatar]').val() != '') {
        formData.append('avatar', $('form').find('input[name=avatar]')[0].files[0], $('form').find('input[name=avatar]').val());
    }
    var id = $('form').find('input[name=id]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: 'admin/edit/'+id,
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {  
            console.log(response);
            $('.update-form-wrapper').html(response.html);

        }
    });
```

**Here is the appended Logs for those that asked:**

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::getBag() (View: /var/www/emailix/resources/views/partials/update_form.blade.php) {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Facade\\Ignition\\Exceptions\\ViewException(code: 0): Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Support\\MessageBag::getBag() (View: /var/www/emailix/resources/views/partials/update_form.blade.php) at /var/www/emailix/resources/views/partials/update_form.blade.php:21)
[stacktrace]
```

I hope that provides some more clearity

Comment: look at logs, there will be logged a reason why you get 500 error

Comment: Thank you @piotr!
This helped me a lot with debugging the problem. I am still getting to know my way around Laravel so you taught me something new!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I spent a while trying to figure this whole thing out. 
I guess that the `render()` directive does not handle `withError()` and `withInput()`.
What I decided to do was just pass the validation errors to the view under an "Alias" if you will so that it bypasses the messageBag.

```
$formErrors =  $validator->errors();
$html = View::make('partials.update_form', compact(['user', 'formErrors']))->render();
return response()->jsons(['html' => $html]);
```

This solved the problem, but I had to handle the blade a bit differently compared to the shorthand methods that are available if you are using the standard $error variable. Here is an example of what my blade looks like now:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control {{ (isset($formErrors) && $formErrors->has('name')) ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}" id="name" name="name" value="{{ old('name', $user->name) }}">
    @if (isset($formErrors) && $formErrors->has('name'))
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $formErrors->first('name') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

I guess I answered my own question for now, but I am still open to suggestions for other workarounds